# How to check for NULL variant values when vt == VT_NULL does not work?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I am maintaining an old system which uses Borland C++ 2007 and AnsiString values (there's nothing I can do about this, the system is phasing out), and I have this use case :

```
// declared in the header as class property
AnsiString str;    // { Data:NULL }

// used in a class method
Variant v = str;

if (v.vt == VT_NULL || v.vt == VT_EMPTY)
{
     // do something
}
```

However `v.vt == 256`, so the condition is false.

When setting `v`, do I need to check `str.IsEmpty()` and set `v.vt = VT_NULL` manually? Preferably, I'd like a universal method, where `str` is unknown, and of unknown type; is this too much to ask?

### Edit

Is there a way to check if a `Variant` is of type `AnsiString`?

Comment: "Manually" is only manual until you write a function to do it.

Comment: "Manually" as in "replace the thousands instances where this happens in the tens of thousands lines of code.

Comment: If you can search-replace into something you can control, like `VT_PRESENT(v)` where that's a macro and/or function which does exactly what you need, you can fuss over the implementation details without having to change a billionty things while testing or improving it. If someone's already hard-coded a mess like that there's nothing you can do easily to change it, so I'm not sure what you're asking about a "universal method" that doesn't require code changes.

Comment: If you've assigned an `AnsiString` to a `Variant` I don't see how the `Variant` can be empty. It will host an `AnsiString` - that may have the length 0.

Comment: Is this a bug you're fixing, or you're just now adding the `AnsiString` case? Sounds like you need a higher level check for the emptiness of the `AnsiString`, and if it is, then set the `Variant` to null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However v.vt == 256, so the condition is false.

256 is `varString`, which is a custom `Variant` type specific to Delphi/C++Builder. There is no `VARTYPE` equivalent of `varString` in the Win32 `VARIANT` API, so you can't use a `Variant` that is holding an `AnsiString` with Win32 `VARIANT` functions.  You would have to make it hold a `BSTR` (`WideString`) instead, which is identified as `varOleStr` (`VT_BSTR`).

> When setting `v`, do I need to check `str.IsEmpty()` and set `v.vt = VT_NULL` manually?

Set it to `varNull` instead.  But yes, if you want the `Variant` to be a Null type, you have to set it that way explicitly (`Variant` is initialized as `varEmpty` by default - yes, there is a difference between Empty and Null).

You can use the RTL's [`Variants::Null()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.Null) function for that purpose, eg:

```cpp
#include <Variants.hpp>

AnsiString str;

...

Variant v;
if (str.IsEmpty())
    v = Null();
else
    v = str;

...

if (VarIsNull(v) || VarIsEmpty(v))
{
    // do something
}
```

> Is there a way to check if a `Variant` is of type `AnsiString`?

The `vt` will be `varString`, as you have noticed.

The RTL has a [`Variants::VarIsStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Variants.VarIsStr) function, which checks for both `varString` (`AnsiString`) and `varOleStr` (`WideString`/`BSTR`), eg:

```cpp
#include <Variants.hpp>

Variant v;

...

if (VarIsStr(v))
{
    AnsiString str = v;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! It did not fix my problem, but It helped me understand C++'s `Variant` type. I'll write a follow up question, but this one has been answered.